# Jquery Ajax Delete call returns 404 not found

Tags: jquery, node.js

Honestly, this is really doing my head in.

This is my jquery delete call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".deleteUser").on("click", deleteUser);
});

function deleteUser() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var confirmation = confirm("are you sure?");
    if (confirmation) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: "/users/delete/"+id
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

And in my node, I have this:

```
app.delete("/users/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
    console.log("id sent:", req.params.id);
    res.send("get a delete call!");
});
```

Obviously, the node file is a lot more than that, but I'm just putting just a section.

When I click on the button that's supposed to initiate the delete, I get the error:

> DELETE http://localhost:3000/users/delete/ 404 (Not Found)

I ran the same URL on my postman, and I'm getting a proper response!

So, when then is the ajax failing? I've checked everything seems alright. I've even stripped the confirmation bit and just gone directly to call the delete, but I'm still getting the same 404.

Please, can anyone spot the error?

**EDIT**
The delete HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <% users.forEach((user) => { %>
    <li><%= user.name %> - <a href="#" class="deleteUser" data-id="<%= user.id %>">Delete</a></li>
    <% }) %>
</ul>
```

I'm using ejs.

Comment: Looks like the `:id` is missing from that URL. What does your `.deleteUser` HTML element look like?

Comment: @Phil I've done that now. Please, have a look

Comment: Can you show an example of the rendered HTML? If it actually has `data-id="some-non-empty-value"`, I have no idea why it isn't working. It might also be good to see some screenshots from your browser's _Network_ console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://localhost:3000/users/delete/

I think your `id` is coming blank. Above url is not a valid request for your node route, you should pass id in above url.

Main issue might be here in your html which renders blank value of user.id

```
data-id="<%= user.id %>"
```

> http://localhost:3000/users/delete/123

Assuming this is from some persistence engine that prefixes `id` properties with an underscore, try

```
data-id="<%= user._id %>"
```

Comment: OP already has `url: "/users/delete/"+id` and as far as I can see, the `id` variable should be set correctly (assuming the `data-id` attribute is set correctly from EJS)

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"Main issue might be here in your html"_? What do you see as the issue?

Comment: Yes I am totally agree with you but I have't seen yet any id is in url `http://localhost:3000/users/delete/` , that is why I am saying that id coming blank.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're actually correct. I did a console log to get what was coming from the id variable and it was empty. Turns out I wasn't referencing the correct key in the user object. The ejs should be data-id="<%= user._id %>" and not data-id="<%= user.id %>"
Thanks!

Comment: Cool Akin_Glen and I think @Phil you should correct your down vote that you done earlier! .

Comment: @NishantDixit hey, I'm just a commenter here

Comment: I added the solution into your answer since it got accepted. Hope you don't mind